# Hide Website menus for external public users in Odoo 8.0 or later

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-website

I want to hide certain menus or pages in the website part of Odoo. I have tried with record rules, but it is not effective. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following module for this. There are configurations to control the visibility of the menu by public users under website settings after you have installed the module.

[Website Menu By User Display](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/website_menu_by_user_status/)

Comment: I have already used. Anyways thank you very much for your answer Gopakumar N G..!!!